# Bounding the degree of irreps of a finite group

Tags: representation-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $\mathbb{k}$ is algebraically closed with characteristic zero. Let $H$ be an Abelian subgroup of $G$. Show that the degree of any irreducible representation $V$ of $G$ is bounded by the index of $H$ in $G$.

Given any irreducible representation $V$ of $G$, I know I can get a representation of $H$ by restricting: $V|_H$. But $H$ is Abelian, so $V|_H$ will be a direct sum of $1$-dimensional, and hence irreducible, representations of $H$...

I just don't see how am I going to be able to say something meaningful about the degree of a representation of $G$. Clearly it will have something to do with counting cosets, so it'd be nice if $H$ were normal, but that need not be the case (I'm guessing, given the way the problem is written.) Any help is appreciated

Comment: You might as well work over the complex field. Let $\chi$ be the character afforded by $V.$ Then $\langle \chi|_{H}, \chi|_{H} \rangle \geq \chi(1)$ since if we write $\chi|_{H} = \sum_{i=1}^{h}m_{i}\lambda_{i}$ where $h = |H|$ and the $\lambda_{i}$ are the irreducible (linear!) characters of $H,$ then  $\langle \chi|_{H}, \chi|_{H} \rangle \geq \chi(1)$ since  $\langle \chi|_{H}, \chi|_{H} \rangle= \sum_{i=1}^{h}m_{i}^{2}.$ On the other hand, this inner product is at most $[G:H]$ since $\chi$ is irreducible for $G$.

Comment: char 0 is superfluous. Res(V) has a 1 dim sub by abelianality of H. So by adjunction V receives a map from a G-rep of dim |G/H|, surjective by irreducibility of V.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: How does irreducibility of $\chi$ imply $\langle \chi|_H, \chi|_H\rangle \le [G:H]$.

Comment: @bartogian: What is adjunction?

Comment: @Bey: Because $\sum_{g \in G} |\chi(g)|^{2} = |G|$, so we certainly have $\sum_{h \in H} |\chi(h)|^{2} \leq  |G|$, with equality if and only if $\chi$ vanishes identically outside $H.$

Comment: Thank you, @GeoffRobinson. If you'd like to submit this as an answer I will gladly accept it